# Do I need to reinstall the app?

Tags: support

After the latest iOS update my phone and CSE are not cooperating like they used to. Is a reinstall of this site’s app in order?

Is there still a app that can be downloaded?

Comment: I don't see reports of it being unusable on [meta stackexchance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=ios+13), although I'd heard a little bit somewhere complaints that the apps are getting a tad neglected so it's good you bring this up. If you've got a meta stackexchange account, that's probably a better place to ask for request, I don't know how likely it is that Community Managers will see this post, but as a programmer myself - I think a tad more detail is in order for this bug report.  you can also use the [tag:bug] tag

Comment: The apps aren't being developed at all unfortunately.

Comment: As noted above and per [this Q&A on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/335251), the mobile apps are no longer supported. That said, most of the website has been/is being redesigned to use responsive design in mobile browsers.